# .NET / Mono Database Engine

Tags: c#, .net, database, mono

Are there any DB engines that are implemented entirely in .NET and Mono compatible?
I would like to have a DB solution that will run on all platforms via Mono so that I don't have to worry about having separate native binaries for each platform.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**[VistaDB](http://www.vistadb.net/)** is fully .NET and supported on Mono. You can embed your DB server into your app with it so there's no extra setup the only issue is this isn't a free product.

**[Firebird](http://firebirdsql.org/dotnetfirebird/index.html)** has a .NET version, and is opensource, which runs on Mono as well. There's also a Lucene adaptor for it incase you want to use that for searches.

Can also give this page a look that lists the supported data providers etc. under Mono

http://www.mono-project.com/Database_Access

Comment: Something I forgot to mention too is you could always design the app using an abstracted DAL so instead of calling out to the DB directly you'd call out to something like CommonDataProvider.GetInstance() and that will get you a reference to the provider set in the config file. Then you could target MSSQL but also MySQL, Oracle etc. and have optimized code for each. That's how apps like community server, graffiti and dotnet nuke work.

Answer (score 6):

[db4o](http://db4o.com/) is an object database engine (written in both Java and C#) that compiles/runs smoothly under Mono.

Answer (score 6):

csharp-sqlite [http://code.google.com/p/csharp-sqlite](http://code.google.com/p/csharp-sqlite/)

Comment: Great! That looks just great.

Comment: While the current version of csharp-sqlite (3.7.7) is Mono compatible, it is neither Linux nor Mac OS X compatible without several changes to the source. /Hopefully/, the next release will be fully Mac OS X/Linux friendly though.

Answer (score 2):

SQLite isn't written in .NET, but there is a .NET adapter (with linq to entities support), and it is portable to all platforms you're likely to consider (it's used for instance in firefox, safari, adobe lightroom, apple's aperture and skype).  If you're looking for a proven, widely adopted, open-license db, it's a good contender.

However, db4o is certainly a good alternative to be mentioned, particularly since it integrates so easily into an OO environment (which sql-based db's tend not to).

Comment: The timing is hilarious ;-).  I'd still use the native bindings initially, though, until the port matures.

Answer (score 1):

[Codegear's BlackFish](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/blackfish_sql/index.php) is aiming for that. I'm not sure about the Mono support.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I would prefer MongoDB as well as Norm C# driver.

Answer (score 1):

[iBoxDB.NET](https://iboxdb.codeplex.com/) can run on most .NET and Mono-based platforms, includes .NET, Mono, Unity3D, Xamarin

Answer (score 0):

I read a short time ago that there is now a .NET port of HSQLDB (a 100% Java database, I would assume that a .NET port is 100% .NET code). The  [web site](http://hsqldb.org/) seems to be down right now but you should take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

The fully-managed [C# port of SQLite3](http://code.google.com/p/csharp-sqlite/) is suggested in other answers, but no release to date supports Linux or Mac OS X despite being compilable with the Mono C# compiler.

A future release will correctly run on those non-Windows platforms with the Mono runtime. With some caveats, the [source repository](http://code.google.com/r/stewartadcock-csharp-sqlite-updates/source) contains working code that can be used now.

Answer (score 0):

I've got one on the go at https://github.com/mcintyre321/PieDb - it's sill

XCOPY deployable
Transparent - you don't need Id properties on your objects*.
It's MIT licenced
It has a very tiny codebase.
It uses a JSON transaction log to record changes (so your objects need to be Json serializable). Can be written to disk, or work in-memory for testing
Transactional sessions (aka Unit Of Work) with optimistic concurrency